# phpMailer - Why is this not working?

Tags: php, authentication, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'sign_up.php';

$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];

if (isset($_POST['btn_signup'])) {

    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

    $name = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $name = trim($_POST['username']);
    $name = strip_tags($name);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);

    $pass = $mysqli->escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
    $pass = trim($_POST['password']);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);
    $pass = htmlspecialchars($pass);

    $hash = $mysqli->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, username, password, hash) VALUES ('$email', '$name', '$pass', '$hash')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    require_once './PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $mail->isSMTP();                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'myGmail@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'myPassword';            // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                          // TCP port to connect to

    $mail->setFrom('myGmail@gmail.com', 'SpreAd Creator');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);   // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addReplyTo('info@gmail.com', 'Info');
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML

    $bodyContent = '<h1>How to Send Email using PHP in Localhost</h1>';
    $bodyContent .= '<p>This is the HTML email sent from localhost using PHP</p>';

    $mail->Subject = 'Email from Localhost';
    $mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

    header("location: other_page.php");
}?>
```

When the user clicks the submit button `if (isset($_POST['btn_signup'])) {...` it should send a confirmation to his email. I don't understand why it doesn't send it. I'm using `phpMailer` instead of `mail()` function which didn't even work. Am I forgetting something?

Comment: You are missing the part where you actually send the email. See Niklesh's answer.

Comment: `escape_string(password_hash($_POST['password']` btw, that's a bad idea. If you want to know why, ask me and I'll tell you why and the rest of the code below that related to it.

Comment: you're also leaving yourself wide open to an sql injection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why is that a bad idea?

Comment: Because, it will cause problems when valid passwords such as `123'\abc&` will be considered as a possible injection and converted to something else, in turn failing when escaping them. Hashing and verifying them with `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` take this into account. Using `strip_tags()` and `htmlspecialchars()` will also do more harm than good. Those by the way, don't help at all against guarding against sql injections; a prepared statement is good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot this at last before header

```
 if (!$mail->send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
  echo "Message sent!";
 }
```

Also check spam folder

Comment: Then you have a different problem - read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide.